# Oracle: Deferring a constraint in a begin/end block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, constraints

How do I defer a constraint inside a begin/end block?

This works:

```
SQL> set constraint t_pk deferred;                                              
Constraint set.
```

But the identical statement fails in a begin/end block:

```
SQL> begin
2  set constraint t_pk deferred;
3  end;
4  /
set constraint t_pk deferred;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `execute immediate`:

```
begin
execute immediate 'set constraint t_pk deferred';
end;
```